# Python - does __init__ get executed after import?

Tags: python

Say that i have the the following folder structure:

```
-api_server
    - __init__.py
-app.py
```

If i have the following code in `__init__.py`:

```
app = config_and_create_app()
```

Then in `app.py` i have:

```
from api_server import app
app.run()
```

will the `import` statement in `app.py` "activate" the `__init__.py` file and therefore `app.run()` will work?

Comment: Did you try it out yourself? It should be easy to found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code in myapp/

```
$ cat myapp/api_server/__init__.py
class App:
    def run(self):
        print("App.run")

def config_and_create_app():
    print("Configuring and creating app")
    return App()

print("init in api server")

app = config_and_create_app()
```

Produces this result when run:

```
$ python myapp/app.py
init in api server
Configuring and creating app
App.run
```

So I'd say, "Yes!"